# Find zero value in one column and get value that is above/below in next column

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list of temperatures from a sensor which includes reset values of zero when the sensor is turned off.

```
A       B       C
res      0
tmp   20,5
tmp   20,3
res      0
tmp   20,4
tmp   20,1
tmp   20,2
res      0
res      0
tmp   20,6
```

I'm able to find such rows with the following formula and get the value from `B`, which is zero:

```
=INDEX(B1:10,MATCH("res",A1:A10,0))
```

But that doesn't do me any good. What I would like is to have the formula find the row with `res` in `A` and then look into the `B` column and find the first non-zero value either above, or below if no such row can be found, e.g. for `A1`.

So my data should look like this:

```
A       B       C
res      0    20,5
tmp   20,5    20,5
tmp   20,3    20,3
res      0    20,3
tmp   20,4    20,4
tmp   20,1    20,1
tmp   20,2    20,2
res      0    20,2
res      0    20,2
tmp   20,6    20,6
```

Will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Insert `=IF(RC[-1]=0,R[-1]C,RC[-1])` into upper Cn where Bn is not zero. Drag down.
Insert `=R[1]C` into Cm above Cn. Drag up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to allow any number of resets at the beginning of the data, and not use any helper columns, the formula is a *little* complicated:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `C1` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill into the rest of the table's column:

```dart
=
INDEX(
  (B:B),
  IFERROR(
    1/(1/SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(ROW(A$1:A1)*(A$1:A1<>"res"),1))),
    ROW()-1+MATCH("tmp",A1:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A:A)),0)
  )
)
```

**Explanation:**

The `LARGE(ROW(A$1:A1)*(A$1:A1<>"res"),1)` function is used to return the largest row number (i.e. closest) non-`res` row, from the current row upwards. (The `SUMPRODUCT()` encapsulating it is just there to ensure that the ranges inside are evaluated as arrays, without requiring the formula to be array-entered.) If there are *no* such non-`res` rows, `SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(…))` evaluates to `0`.

For a non-zero *value*, `IFERROR(1/(1/value),expression)` evaluates to *value* (i.e the closest upwards non-`res` row number). For a zero *value*, it evaluates to the result of *expression* (since `1/(1/0))` results in a `#DIV/0!` error).

Thus, for every consecutive reset value starting from the first row, `ROW()-1+MATCH("tmp",A1:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A:A)),0)` is evaluated. This simply returns the row number of the first row, from the current row downwards, that is a valid temperature reading. ( `A1:INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A:A))` is simply the range from the cell in column `A` corresponding to the current row, i.e. `A1` for the formula entered in `C1`, to the last cell of column `A`, `INDEX(A:A,ROWS(A:A))`.)

Finally, we end up with `INDEX((B:B),row_number)` which extracts the appropriate temperature reading.

Stepping through the formula in `C10` should make the above clearer:

- `ROW(A$1:A10)*(A$1:A10<>"res")`
  → `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}*({"res";"res";"tmp";"tmp";"res";"tmp";"tmp";"tmp";"res";"res"}<>"res")`
  → `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}*{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}`
  → `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}*{0;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;0;0}`
  → `{0;0;3;4;0;6;7;8;0;0}`
- `1/(1/SUMPRODUCT(LARGE({0;0;3;4;0;6;7;8;0;0},1)))`
  → `1/(1/SUMPRODUCT(8))` (since `LARGE()` returns the n-th largest value, where n is the second argument) 
  → `1/(1/8)`
  → `1/0.125`
  → `8`
- `=INDEX((B:B),IFERROR(8,…))`
  → `=INDEX(B:B,8)`
  → `=20,2`

**Notes:**

- The multi-line, prettified formula actually works entered as is.
- The brackets around `(B:B)` are only required to force the `B:B` to remain on its own line.

---

If you would like a simpler formula, then you need to use a helper column (`D`):

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `C1` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill into the rest of the table's column:

```dart
=IF(A1="res",IF(ROW()=1,D1,INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1)),B1)
```

Enter the following formula in `D1` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down/auto-fill into the rest of the table's column:

```dart
=IF(A1="res",D2,B1)
```

**Explanation:**

- Helper column:

  - If the current row contains a reset value, the formula in column `D` copies the value from the cell directly below.
  - Otherwise, it grabs the value from the same row of column `B`.
  - Working from the last data row in the column upwards, this leads to `D1` evaluating to the first valid reading in column `B`.
- Main column:

  - For a reset row, the formula in column `C` checks if it is in the first row, and if so it uses the value from the cell of column `D` corresponding to the same row, i.e. `D1`. If the formula is in any other row of column `C`, it grabs the value from the cell immediately above.
  - If the row is a valid temperature row, the formula grabs the temperature reading from the cell in column `B` corresponding to the same row.

Comment: This is working great. Thank you for comprehensive answer. I've learn something from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just look for the "res" and grab the value above.
Even if there is multiple zero values they should point to the one above which is not zero since we just changed it.

So in C1

```
=B1
```

Then C2

```
=IF(A2<>"res",B2,C1)
```

And fill down.
This will work as long as the B1 is not 0.
You could add a formula to take care of that too, but since it's one cell, I think it's easier to check it manually since you are placing the other formula right next to it.